# MySQL query assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Here is a description of the table i am using:

```
describe mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| classId   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| studentId | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| quizGrade | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| quizId    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Here is example data in the database:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+
| Student ID | Last Name | First Name | Quiz ID | Quiz Grade |
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+
| A1         | Cat       | Tom        |      19 |       75   |
| A2         | pancake   | Harry      |      19 |       65   |
| A5         | Worthy    | Dick       |      19 |       NULL |
| A1         | Cat       | Tom        |      20 |       55   |
| A2         | pancake   | Harry      |      21 |       NULL |
| A2         | pancake   | Harry      |      20 |       47   |
| A5         | Worthy    | Dick       |      20 |       95   |
| A1         | Cat       | Tom        |      21 |       55   |
| A5         | Worthy    | Dick       |      21 |       95   |
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

The result i am trying to get is one that will look similar to the following:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
| Student ID | Last Name | First Name | Quiz 19 | Quiz 20    | Quiz 21    |
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
| A1         | Cat       | Tom        |      75 |       55   |       55   |
| A2         | pancake   | Harry      |      65 |       47   |       NULL |
| A5         | Worthy    | Dick       |     NULL|       95   |       95   |
+------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

- Where the Student ID column is unique.
- Where the quiz columns continue depending on how many quizzes are in
  the original table. And the quiz columns contain the grade of each of
  the respective students.

Comment: FYI - The technical term for what you are trying to do is called "pivot tables"

Comment: @ChrisLively: Wow, thanks! Found some great examples. I did not know the correct term. What i was trying was WAY off... =(

Comment: The text you keep adding provides no value to your question.  Funny that you keep re-adding it instead of demonstrating you've actually tried to figure this out yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 select s.StudentId, s.FirstName, s.LastName, 
 Case when s.QuizId = 19 then quizGrade end as 'Quiz 19',
 Case when s.QuizId = 20 then quizGrade end as 'Quiz 20',
 Case when s.QuizId = 21 then quizGrade end as 'Quiz 21'
 from StudentRecordTable2 sr 
 inner join Students s on sr.StudentId = s.StudentId
```

see [this](http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf)